# Error: 'str ' object does not support item assignment python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Error: 'str ' object does not support item assignment python

```
dict=['A', 'a','B', 'b','C', 'c','D', 'd','E', 'e','F', 'f','G', 'g','H', 'h','I',       'i','J', 'j','K', 'k','L', 'l','M', 'm','N', 'n','P', 'o','P', 'p','Q', 'q','R', 'r','S',                   's','T', 't','U', 'u','V', 'v','W', 'w','X', 'x','Y', 'y','Z' 'z']

def cript(s):
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        a=dict.index(s[i])
        if a<26:
            s[i]=dict[a+26]
        else:
            s[i]=dict[a-26]
    return s

print cript('Hello')
```

Error line 6

```
    s[i]= dict[a+26]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment python
```

Comment: It's exactly what it says. You are not allowed to change characters in the middle of a string in Python.

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue, but it's a very bad idea to reuse built-in names for other objects. In your code, `dict` is a list instance, which may be very confusing in the future when you try to create an actual dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not allow you to swap out characters in a string for another one; strings are immutable. What you'll need to do is create a totally different string and return that instead.

```
dict=['A', 'a','B', 'b','C', 'c','D', 'd','E', 'e','F', 'f','G', 'g','H', 'h','I', 'i','J', 'j','K', 'k','L', 'l','M', 'm','N', 'n','P', 'o','P', 'p','Q', 'q','R', 'r','S', 's','T', 't','U', 'u','V', 'v','W', 'w','X', 'x','Y', 'y','Z' 'z']

def cript(s):
    crypt_s = ""
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        a=dict.index(s[i])
        if a<26:
            crypt_s += dict[a+26]
        else:
            crypt_s += dict[a-26]
    return crypt_s

print cript('Hello')
```

Of course, there may be other issues with the code, but that will solve that specific error message.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable objects, meaning they can't be modified in place (you'd have to return a new string and reassign it).

```
s[i] = dict[a + 26]
```

is trying to reassign a value in the string

Here is an easier to see example

```
>>> astring = "Hello"
>>> astring[0] = "a"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    astring[0] = "a"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def game():
    list = ["pomme", "anniversaire", "table", "travail", "amies", "enfants"]
    ran = random.randint(0, (len(list)-1)/2)
    mot = list[ran]
    length = len(mot)
    for x in range(0, length-1):
        if length % 2 ==0:
            a = int(random.randint(-length/2, length/2))
        else:
            a = int(random.randint(-(length-1)/2, (length-1)/2))
        mot[x] = mot[x+a]
```